# На главной странице не работает форма отправки данных на e-mail через ajax

Tags: ajax

На [сайте](http://olgamag24.ru) есть форма отправки данных на e-mail, работающая через ajax.

Проблема в том, что на главной странице `olgamag24.ru` форма не работает, даже алерта нет об отправке, отправки данных тем более, а точно такая же форма, с таким же кодом на `olgamag24.ru/form_ajax` работает исправно.

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: работает и даже больше, чем нужно. Уберите повторные таги скриптовых файлов из кода страницы.

Comment: `$(this).find("input")` в `done` - бессмысленно, так как `this` в этом месте это не форма.